# Trying to find the T(n) function and complexity in this bit of Python

Tags: python, function, big-o

```
def wum(aList):
    a = 7
    b = 5
    n = len(aList)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            a = i * a
            b = j * j
            w = i * j
            v = i + w
        x = v * v
        for k in range(n):
            w = a * k + 23
            v = b * b
        a = w + v
```

I got `T(n) = 2n + 6n^2` complexity `O(n^2)`, does that seem right? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find it a bit difficult to give an exact value for `T(n)` since it’s hard to define what `1` means there. But assuming that each of those assignments is `1` (regardless of what kind of calculation happens), then the total `T(n)` would be as following: `n * (6n + 2) + 3`.

But in big-O notation, that is `O(n²)`, yes. You can easily see that since you have two nested loop levels, both over `n`.

---

Btw. your function is probably an example from your instructor or something, but it’s really a bad example. You can easily modify the logic to be in linear and yield the same results:

```
a = 7
b = 5
n = len(aList)
for i in range(n):
    a *= i ** n # `a` is multiplicated `n` times by (constant) `i`
    b = (n - 1) ** 2 # at the end of the loop, `j` is `(n - 1)`
    v = i + (i * b) # at the end of the loop, `w` is `i * b`
    x = v * v
    w = a * (n - 1) + 23 # at the end of the loop, `k` is `(n - 1)`
    v = b ** 2 # `b` (and as such `v`) is never changed in the loop
    a = w + v
```

And since nothing of that uses any value of the list, you could actually make these calculations in constant time too (I’ll leave that for your exercise ;) ).

And finally, you could argue that since the function does not return anything, and also does not mutate the input list, the function is a big NO-OP, and as such can be replaced by a function that does nothing:

```
def wum(aList):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you! That explanation was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @seawork Glad to hear that! Please remember [to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) if it solved your question to mark it as resolved.